# Problems generating a rig with Rigify

Tags: rigging, rigify

I used Rigify to create a rig for a character that I want to animate. I added in a human meta-rig and formed it to fit the human model. The problem occurs when I click generate under the Rigify buttons category. It does not create points for me to manipulate for the fingers, elbows or knees or a full skeleton for the character. Any ideas why?

[image: this is the outcome of what I made]

[image: the rig when it is formed to the body]

[image: the solid view]

Comment: I guess you are using rigify? Please attach some screenshots showing your right, your model and the resulting animation rig.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure 'Auto Run Python Scripts' is ticked in the File -> User Preferences Menu. I had the same problem and that fixed it.

Comment: Umm... no. Where the heck is that tickbox?!

Comment: Under the File -> User Preferences -> File Tab, near the bottom

Comment: For anyone coming across this as of 2.80, it's now in the `Edit -> Preferences -> Save & Load` menu

Answer (score 3):

Armatures have their own layering system - similar to the layers available in the 3dview - only bones on active layers will be visible. Rigify uses these layers to group various related bones together, eg the finger bones are all on one layer, arm.L(IK) bones are on another and so on.

Rigify also creates a panel that is shown in the properties sidebar of the 3dview (<kbd>N</kbd>) that has buttons to enable the various bone layers using more useful names. These buttons are just a convenience that relate to the bone layers available in the armature properties.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Last Box to Check Under File > Blender Preferences > "File Tab" then at the bottom where it says "Auto Execution" ..It fixed it for me.